# Signing files with some kind of "inheritance"

Tags: rsa, signature

I'd like to design a system where the following situation happens:

1. I (person 1) have some secret key
2. I hand out another secret key to a developer (person 2)
3. Person 2 signs several files with his secret key
4. Person 2 can now distribute his software among with mine to the users.
5. In my software I'd like to be able to check if the digital signature is valid.

I'd like to check if the digital signature with the code person 2 made is valid.

Person 2 could distribute the public key among with his files, so I could check it, but that would be way too prone to attacks which could replace the public key and resign the file.

Also, there would be multiple developers with their own different secret keys. I wouldn't like to embed every single public key into my software, the best would be if I could create some kind of "SUPER KEY", or I don't know how to describe.

**Obviously I'm willing to make compromises if the given solution doesn't match my previously described workflow, but achieves the same thing.**

I'm curious if there's some already existing cryptographic algorithm which would suit my needs.
I was thinking of some RSA-related things, but according to my very limited knowledge, it's not really possible without embedding all the keys.

Comment: This you see certificate chaining?

Comment: Indeed you should have a look at _public key infrastructures_ and _X.509 certificates_.